# Grammatical quirk in Yoda-esque sentences

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

Usually when the word אתה appears in Tanach and tfilah, we pronounce it מלרע (a-TAH or a-TOH. whichever you like, that's not really my point. The emphasis is on the end of the word).

Why in Yoda-esque sentences* do we emphasize the first syllable instead and pronounce it מלעיל (A-tah, with emphasis on the beginning of the word)?

I'm looking for a specific grammatical rule that doesn't involve Star Wars references.

*Such as מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים אַתָּה (resurrecter of the dead you are) and מוחֵל וְסולֵחַ אָתָּה

Comment: Who's 'we'? Is this something done because of tradition or because of lack of Hebrew language knowledge?

Comment: If you look in artscroll siddurim (and I think a couple of other siddurim also), there's a little vertical line under some words. I don't have one on me right now to double check, but I'm pretty sure those lines are there to tell you which syllable should be emphasized.

Comment: Its some grammar rule. Just head about it the other day. Another example is בחר בנו in bircot torah: even though בחר is generally מלרע, it becomes מלעיל when followed by a מלעיל word. BTW the words you're looking for are מלרע = emphasis on the last part of the word vs. מלעיל = emphasis on an earlier part of the word.

Comment: @Vram- I figured it was a grammatical rule. Hence the title and tag. Do you know what the rule is? I just noted a pattern. It isn't really a "rule."

Comment: @AriA It is a rule indeed, I learned it from a Hebrew Grammar teacher. I don't remember what it's called, but I can ask him next time I see him. If you are aware that it is a rule in the question, what then are you asking? For its particulars?

Comment: @Vram. Yes. I guess that's not so clear from the question. I'll edit it. sorry

Comment: @AriA why the removal of proper terms (מלעיל/מלרע)?

Comment: @Vram. I think we were editing the question at the same time so whatever you added got deleted when I pressed save

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/162/1172

Comment: @ Vram. I guess, but I think there's an extremely fine line between a question about Hebrew grammar (especially one that was inspired by the text of the siddur) and a question about Judaism.

Comment: @AriA you have nothing to worry about unless 4 other people (or a mod) agree with me.

Comment: It's called the pausal form. Some words normally stressed as milra changed to mileil when they occur at a pause such as an etnachta or sof pasuk. It has has to do with their vowels. Sorry I can't find more info.

Comment: @Shemmy I thought pausal forms was when a segolite changes from a segol to a kamatz (like kesef becomes kasef) by an atnach or sof pasuk.

Comment: Who is this "@vram", anyways? People keep referencing @vram, but I see no name such as that. Is this the person who signs with two obscene looking dots? Why the need for a signature like that? What message are you trying to send by doing this?

Comment: @Vram Shemmy is definitely right on this one. Other pausal changes are things like תאכלו Toe-che-LU into Toe-CHAI-lu

Comment: @ Shemmy. Yes, that's Vram. I'm not sure why (or if) you find the dots offensive but he did that a couple of weeks (or months, I have no idea) ago

Comment: I understand that vowels change according to stresses and other reasons, but the original question was concerning the stress. I already alluded to the change in vowels in my original response, so Two-Dots didn't really add anything. Yes, the tenu'a k'tana (patach) changes to a tenu'a g'dola (kamatz). But the original poster's question still stands: What is the rule for the change in STRESS? The change in stress (along with the vowels) occurs in pausal forms. The original poster is looking for that rule. Two-Dots has not answered it, and giving more examples does not answer it, either.

Comment: @Shemmy I'm assuming that I am Two-Dots. I never claimed to have answered the question, and neither did anyone else, (which is why, on the the title page, this question still has 0 answers and not 1). I questioned you on your word choice of calling this type of shifting the stress *pausal form*, but considering other users agree with you, I seem to have been wrong. Also, nobody discussed changing a patach to a kamatz: i mentioned changing a segol to a kamatz and DoubleAA mentioned changing milra to mil'el, as did you.

Comment: Two-Dots (that's your signature), mention of the change from a patach to a kamatz is by default since this is the example the original poster uses. (Even though Ari A doesn't specify it, this is what happens in his example word "atah.") The grammar rule is related to tenu'ot katanot (lesser vowels) not being able to carry the stress in the pausal position. Both segol and patach (among others) are tenu'ot katanot, which is why the word cherev (stressed milra) changes to charev (stressed mileil) in the pausal form. But I still don't know why the stress shifts in the first place.

Comment: Correction: I was wrong before when I said that a tenu'a ketana cannot carry the stress. I just saw that the word ארץ does, in fact, sometimes carry the stress on a segol. In Psalm 67 (which we say for s'firat ha-omer), the word ארץ (eretz; land) carries the mil'eil (penultimate) stress in both the pausal form (disjunctive) and in another form with which I am not familiar (conjunctive?). I'm wondering now if it's not so much a matter of vowels as it is a matter of certain nouns having two forms (conjunctive and disjunctive?). What rule, then, governs which nouns fall under this rule?

Comment: To continue the above comment -- the interesting thing is that the word ארץ does, in fact, change its mil'eil (stressed penultimate) vowel from a tenu'a ketanah (segol) to tenu'a gedolah (kamatz) when it appears in the pausal (disjunctive) form. When the word appears in the conjunctive form, however, the segol does carry the stress.

Comment: See also a discussion of the grammatical rule of pausal forms under the question "Why lachem and not lechem?" In fact, there, @Shalom discusses the pausal form of the word אתה which is the very question which started this thread.

Comment: To those who are advocating closure: This is a question about proper accenting and pronunciation of prayer and is therefore definitely in-scope.

Comment: @Vram FTR My example also changed a sheva into a tzeirei.

Comment: @IsaacMoses can't that be said about any grammar question?

Comment: @ه ه, it could be said about any question about Biblical or Rabbinic Hebrew that affects the pronunciation of prayer or the understanding of the meaning of the holy texts or liturgy. I believe this standard is consistent with both of the top-voted answers to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/162/in-what-respects-are-hebrew-language-questions-in-scope

Answer (score 4):

Many words in Biblical Hebrew have a "pausal form", which differs slightly from its regular form in stress and/or vocalization.  This form is usually used at the end of a phrase, although the regular form may also be used at the end of a phrase.  For example, in the Song of the Sea *natitha yeminekha tibla`emo ares*, the word "land" appears as *ares* instead of *eres*.  Similarly, in Ps 43:3 we read *el har **qodsheKHA*** [-shin-shewa-khaf-qames] *we'el mishkenothekha*, but in Ps 15:1, we read *mi yishkon behar **qodSHEkha*** [-shin-seghol-khaf-qames].

These forms usually appear with major disjunctive accents (silluq, athnah), but sometimes with minor disjunctives (such as zarqa, rebhia`).  The word "you" (masc sing) is one of the few that have two pausal forms, a minor one aleph-pathah-taw-qames-he' and a major one aleph-qames-taw-qames-he', both with penultimate stress (i.e., stress on next-to-last syllable).  The regular form (aleph-pathah-taw-qames-he' with stress on the last syllable) occurs 455 times in Tanakh (221 with disjunctive accents, 225 with conjunctive), the minor pausal 27 times, and the major pausal 52 times.

In the prayerbook, when it is not a quotation from Tanakh, the use of pausal form is usually a result of a movement in the late eighteenth - early nineteenth century c.e. to apply the rules of Biblical Hebrew grammar to the Rabbinic Hebrew of the siddur.

See [Gesenius 29](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/29)i-v; Weingreeen (*A Practical Grammar for Classical Hebrew*) p. 137; Jacobson (*Chanting the Hebrew Bible*) pp. 340ff.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Please consider joining [the Hebrew Language stack exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage?referrer=wapPkFrM1oVpaSf89lZ05w2) proposal, which needs more participants to launch as a beta.